# C Program Runs Surprisingly Slow

Tags: c, performance, compiler-construction

A simple program I wrote in C takes upwards of half an hour to run. I am surprised that C would take so long to run, because from what I can find on the internet C ( aside from C++ or Java ) is one of the faster languages.

```
// this is a program to find the first triangular number that is divisible by 500 factors

int main()
{
    int a; // for triangular num loop
    int b = 1; // limit for triangular num (1+2+3+......+b)
    int c; // factor counter
    int d; // divisor
    int e = 1; // ends loop
    long long int t = 0; // triangular number in use

    while( e != 0 )
    {   
        c = 0;

        // create triangular number t
        t = t + b;
        b++;

        // printf("%lld\n", t); // in case you want to see where it's at
        // counts factors
        for( d = 1 ; d != t ; d++ )
        {       
            if( t % d == 0 )
            {
                c++;
            }       
        }

        // test to see if condition is met
        if( c > 500 )
        {
            break;  
        }
    }

    printf("%lld is the first triangular number with more than 500 factors\n", t);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Granted the program runs through a lot of data, but none of it is ever saved, just tested and passed over.

I am using the Tiny C Compiler on Windows 8.

Is there a reason this runs so slowly? What would be a faster way of achieving the same result?

Thank you!

Comment: Why is this tagged java/c++?

Comment: [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12) solutions typically require mathematical insight to optimize the program. **`PRO_TIP:`** If you don't know the mathematical insight, at least use a [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) technique. Best help I can give without spoiling the solution for you.

Comment: @LaszloPapp There's a `break;` inside the loop.

Comment: Are you expecting optimizations from your compiler?

Comment: `e != 0` is unnecessary, although propably optimised away by a clever compiler. Btw: Did you turn compile time optimisation on?

Comment: I thought Java/C++ was relevant as in " would these be faster ". Not super important.

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but you really shouldn't use single letter variable names unless it's appropriate (e.g. X and Y coordinates and even those should be further qualified), or it's something like a loop counter that isn't referenced inside the loop.
More importantly, even if you use single-letters, don't go `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`; use letters that make sense

Comment: The problem is with your algorithm, not with C; brute force techniques are inherently very slow. You can use the "fastest" programming language out there, but if you have a slow algorithm, your program will still be slow.

Comment: @hexafraction can you explain compiler optimizations or link me something that does? I'm still relatively new to all this.

Comment: I consider the code brain-dead.

Comment: *"I am surprised that C would take so long to run, because from what I can find on the internet C ( aside from C++ or Java ) is one of the faster languages."* The language has near-nothing to do with it in this case. Its how you're using it (and usually most always is).

Comment: For starters, looping to `t` looking for factors of `t` is nuts, especially for large `t` values. Consider looping only to the floor of the square root of `t`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: some factors of a number are bigger than the square root of the number.  For example, 6 is a factor of 12, but 6 is larger than 3 or 4 (the possible values for the square root of 12).  But I agree that the search should be handled entirely differently (prime factors and combinations thereof, perhaps?)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Certainly. I was somewhat losing my marbles for a moment. Adding in both factors in an `a*b=c` through all qualified `a <= sqrt(c)` is more along the lines of what I was going for. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over a ton of numbers you don't need to. By definition, a positive factor is any whole number that can be multiplied by another to obtain the desired product.

```
Ex: 12 = 1*12, 2*6, and 3*4
```

The order of multiplication are NOT considered when deciding factors. In other words,

```
Ex: 12 = 2*6 = 6*2
```

The order doesn't matter. 2 and 6 are factors *once*.

The square root is the one singleton that will come out of a factoring of a product that stands alone. All others are in pairs, and I hope that is clear. Given that, you can significantly speed up your code by doing the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// this is a program to find the first triangular number that is divisible by 500 factors

int main()
{
    int c = 0;                  // factor counter
    long long int b = 0;        // limit for triangular num (1+2+3+......+b)
    long long int d;            // divisor
    long long int t = 0;        // triangular number in use
    long long int r = 0;        // root of current test number

    while (c <= 500)
    {
        c = 0;

        // next triangular number
        t += ++b;

        // get closest root.
        r = floor(sqrt(t));

        // counts factors
        for( d = 1 ; d < r; ++d )
        {
            if( t % d == 0 )
                c += 2;  // add the factor *pair* (there are two)
        }
        if (t % r == 0)  // add the square root if it is applicable.
            ++c;
    }

    printf("%lld is the first triangular number with more than 500 factors\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this [on IDEOne.com](http://ideone.com/HdF0nQ) takes less than two seconds to come up with the following:

**Output**

```
76576500 is the first triangular number with more than 500 factors
```

I hope this helps. (and I *think* that is the correct answer). There are certainly more efficient ways of doing this ([see here](http://www.mathblog.dk/triangle-number-with-more-than-500-divisors/) for some spoilers if you're interested), but going with your code idea and seeing how far we could take it was the goal of this answer.

Finally, this finds the first number with MORE than 500 factors (i.e. 501 or more) as per your output message. Your comment at the top of the file indicates you're looking for the first number with 500-or-more, which does not match up with your output message.

Answer (score 1):

Without any math analysis:

```
  ...

  do 
  {   
    c = 0;
    t += b;
    b++;

    for (d = 1; d < t; ++d)
    {       
      if (!(t % d))
      {
        c++;
      }       
    }
  } while (c <= 500);

  ...
```

Comment: alright that is another way to hold the loop and break it. would it make the code run any faster though?

Comment: @Charles: Depends on how clever the compiler is. I doubt a recent gcc would show any differences.

Comment: @Charles: However, did you apply any profiling on different approaches to code it?

Comment: Profiling?

And after changing my while to while(c<=500) and doing away with the unnecessary if statement I now get 0 every time.

Comment: and is there a reason that you changed it from a `while(test){}` to a `do{}while(test)`? is one better than the other?

Comment: so now whatever my starting `t` value is is my answer. which is incorrect.

Comment: @Charles: Profiling implies performance mesurements. Google it.

Comment: The `do {} while ()` just follows the logic of the flow: Under any conditions do run at least 1 time. So there is no need to test on top, but earliest on bottom.

Comment: It still only works when I use my original `while( e != 0 )` loop. not with the other loop.

Comment: @Charles: Check for typos, compile with symbols (`-g` for gcc) and then run the program in a debugger (gdb).

Comment: @Charles: If I run my version with `50` but `500` I get `25200` as result (with initially setting `t=0`).

Comment: @Charles: For `500` I get `2162160`.

Comment: Weird.. Alright. I'll look into that. If no better answer comes up in a bit I'll choose yours.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing an O(n^2) algorithm.  It would be surprising if the code took less than a half an hour.

Refer to your computer science textbook for a better method compared to this brute force method of: check 1, 1 + 2, 1 + 2 + 3, etc.

You might be able to shorten the inner for loop.  Does it really need to check all the way up to t for factors that divide the triangular number.  For example, can 10 be evenly divisible by any number greater than 5? or 100 by any number greater than 50?

Thus, given a number N, what is the largest number that can evenly divide N?
Keep reading/researching this problem.

Also, as other people have mentioned, the outer loop could be simply coded as:

```
  while (1)
  {
    // etc.
  }
```

So, no need need to declare `e`, or `a`?  Note, this doesn't affect the length of time, but your coding style indicates you are still learning and thus a reviewer would question everything your code does!!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some unnecessary operations, and I think those instructions are not at all required if we can check that simply.

first :

```
while(e!=0)
```

as you declared `e=1`, if you put only `1` in loop it will work. You are not updating value of `e` anywhere.

Change that and check whether it works fine or not.

Comment: `t` is not always updated with 1. It's updated `b` and `b` is always increasing with `1`, so `t` is increasingly increasing.

Comment: the while(e != 0) was just a way to hold the loop until the condition was met. then the loop is broken using break;

t does not increase by 1 each time, it moves to the next triangular number.

Comment: @TimvanElsloo... Thanks for updating me... I didn`t check that.

Answer (score 0):

One of the beautiful things about triangle numbers, is that if you have a triangle number, with a simple addition operation, you can have the next one.